# Can you merge SSRS servers together other than manually moving each report

Tags: reporting-services

How can I merge the reports from seperate reporting servers into 1 location? In my current situation I am faced with 3 different reporting servers, each one used by a seperate department. 2 of them are running SSRS 2008r2, the third SSRS 2005.

I want to decommission the server that is running SSRS 2005 and then combine all the reports into one location to make things more maintainable.

There is about 100 reports in total. Nearly all of these use the same datasource. Is there any easy way these all on one database? Through sql, upload multiple reports at once, etc. I am currently not worried about permissions, just migrating all of the reports and setting the datasource for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Reporting Services Scripter](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62). It won't do the merge for you, but it greatly simplifies copying published reports between servers. Data source credentials don't transfer between servers, you'll need to update usernames/passwords after the transfer is complete.